# 2D Incompressible Fluid Simulation solving / diffusion factor

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulations, differential-equations, navier-stokes

I've been reading about fluid simulations - specifically, incompressible fluid dynamics using the incompressible Navier-Stokes equations. Every resource I've looked at has two key components that I don't understand. First, when looking at solving for densities, we have the equation $d_n=d_c+k(d_c+s_c)$ where $d_n$ represents the density of a cell at the next timestep, $d_c$ represents the density of a cell at the current timestep, and $s_c$ which represents the density of the surrounding cells (specifically non-diagonal cells), and additionally $k$ which serves as some constant of rate transfer between cells.

[This paper](https://damassets.autodesk.net/content/dam/autodesk/www/autodesk-reasearch/Publications/pdf/realtime-fluid-dynamics-for.pdf) which is one of the most cited in the topic, suggests that this is an unstable method for large $k$, however, I don't see why we do not simple restrict $k$ to the range $0\leq k \leq 1$ given that if k is larger than 1 matter is created out of nothing, and less than 0 meaning matter is destroyed without purpose?

My other key point of confusion comes from something I mentioned above, the use of only the non-diagonal cells. Why do most of these methods not look at diagonal cells, would this not improve the accuracy of these models?

I apologize for a possible lack of understanding or communication; I am nowhere near a Physicist by trade and I am simply exploring this concept and trying to learn. Thank you all in advance for any information!

Comment: Isn't the density constant for an incompressible fluid?  Or is it just spatially non-constant?

Comment: This has been super poorly communicated throughout most of the paper's I've read honestly. I believe the density is constant, however, we assume you place something like dye in the liquid and the density is actually referring to this dye and how it distributes. The best explanation I've found for it is here: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/fluid-simulation-for-dummies.html under the last paragraph of the "basic" section. @ChetMiller

Comment: To quote the article "The water is equally dense everywhere, but some of it has more dye than others, and this variation lets us see things moving. So remember, whenever I'm talking about "density", I'm actually talking about the density of the dye, not the density of the fluid. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what they are trying to do here, but I'm not sure that the approach they use gives the actual solution to the equations as stated.  Not that that matters, because it is only a simulation, and not an attempt for really quantify what is happening.  The second equation actually describes the transport and generation of an inert tracer species (of low concentration) in a fluid flow.  Their numerical method goes unstable for large time steps, so this is where they have to use a cap on the "diffusion" parameter to keep the solution stable.

There is a reason they do not include the diagonal cells.  When they reduce their differential equation to a finite difference approximation, the diagonal cells do not come into play.  If there were 2nd cross partial derivative terms (which there are not), the diagonal cells would have to be included.